# Copy Python code without indentation from VSCode for pasting into debugger console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have some nested Python code, say:

```
def foo(bar):
  if bar:
    print("Lookee here!")
    print("Both of these lines")

breakpoint()
```

I want to be able to highlight both print lines, and copy-paste them into the debugger console.

You can alt-click (multicursor) and then shift+end (multi cursor select), but a) this is easy to muck up / arduous, and b) generates a `*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` error.

Ideas? Search terms? Plugins?

Update:

From a terminal:

```
(.venv) $ python3
Python 3.7.8 (default, Jul  8 2020, 14:16:55) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>     print("Lookee here!")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("Lookee here!")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     print("Both of these lines")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("Both of these lines")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: I copied and pasted two print sentences into the debug console and found nothing wrong. can you paste your debug console both input and error screenshot?

Comment: Interesting. I should have tried my small example! I will about narrowing down the actual situation to something I can share on the 'net.

Comment: Have your question been solved? if solved, It's appreciated that you post the solution as the answer will help other people.

Comment: @MollyWang It has not.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you copy this two sentences with inappropriate blank space which violates the python syntax rules. When you select them, put the cursor before the first `print()` sentence then press:

```
Ctrl+Alt+Down -> Shift+Alt+Right
```

then copy and paste them to debug console, you can get the right output:
[image]

Comment: Ohhh. Keyboard shortcuts for the multicursor, I like. To be clear: Should the initial cursor placement be at the start of the line, or at the end of the indentation whitespace?

Comment: nope, put the cursor before your code is enough, not the start of line. make sure when you copy them to debug console, no surplus blank space included. does this help to solve your question?

Comment: definitely looks like it, although I'll wait to accept until I know for sure. thanks regardless, and upvotes made!

Comment: @Narfanator, look at this, It will raise an IndentationError if there’s a line in a code block that has the wrong number of spaces: https://realpython.com/invalid-syntax-python/#using-the-wrong-indentation